# Why won't Entourage work with Exchange 2007?

Tags: email, dll, exchange-server, entourage

So this is IT more than programming but Google found nothing, and you guys are just the right kind of geniuses.

**My Exchange Server 2007 and Entourage clients don't play nice.**

Right now the big issue is that the entourage client will not connect to Exchange 2007  ( Entourage 2004 or 2008)

The account settings are correct and use the proper format of `https://exchange2007.mydomain.com/exchange/user@domain.com`

The issue is with a dll called **davex.dll** when it is where it belongs, the OWA application pool crashes a whole bunch of nasty things happen.

When it isn’t there, I can connect to everything fine - and the OWA app pool doesn’t crash - but Entourage never propogates the folders in the mailbox and doesn't send or receive.

Any help or ideas would be appreciated:  Microsoft support is silent on the issue, and Google doesn't turn up much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it without using the /exchange in the server properties field.  Here's a link with relevant [info](http://www.robichaux.net/blog/2006/09/using_entourage_with_exchange_2007.php).

Answer (score 0):

davex.dll is the legacy webdav component for Exchange server, which Entourage uses. Your first step should be investigating why the application pool crashes. My guess is that Entourage can't do anything when the dll isn't present because webdav is not responding to any requests.